# Unable to connect to TP-Link wireless router with iPad 2

Tags: ios, ipad, network, wifi, router

I work in an office of 3 developers, all of whom own an iPad. Two of the developers have an iPad 3, and I have an iPad 2.

I am the only one that cannot connect to the TP-Link TL-WA801ND Wireless Router.

I have tried the classic troubleshooting technique of turning the router and iPad off and back on again, but to no avail.

My iPad 2 model number is `MC769B/A` and I am running iOS 7.0.4 `(11B554a)`.

I can connect to the building's Wifi network fine, and also when i'm at home I can connect to my own router and extender without any problems.

What could be the reason that I can't connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite going through the TP-Link support channels I ended up resolving this problem by using the 'Forget this network' option in iOS and then manually connecting again by entering the AP name.

[image]